# Can a salesperson be a good UX designer, as compared to who are not?

Tags: user-behavior, career-development

Can a salesperson be a good UX designer, as compared to who are not?

I just want to know, if a person who knows how to play with users mind, OR read the users mind would be a good UX designer as compared to who dont?

Comment: Well, my experience with interviewing sales staff is that they are generally good at thinking what type of basic content that should be on the web site, since they have a lot of contact with the customers.

Comment: Thank you for answering. the reason i asked, is I have plenty of work experience in web sales and now i am a web designer. I am now interested in either UX or UI designer.

Comment: What do you mean by 'UX Designer'? This could mean many things - someone who gets the requirements from the client, someone who writes specifications, someone who builds prototypes, someone who produces the visual designs, someone who creates the front-end of the site, someone who codes the website...

Comment: Marketing/Sales are a different focus than User Experience. But a person could certainly be good at both.

Comment: A salesperson can convince people that he's a good UX designer. Works best at agencies, not so well in-house.

Comment: As-is I don't think this post is gathing constructive answers so I've closed it. I think a better question would explain *why* you're wondering this. Do you think knowing sales gives you an advantage/disadvantage in the UX field? Why? Is there something you're trying to overcome? Feel free to edit the post and we can reopen once it's suitable for our format

Answer (score 2):

Having a deep understanding or empathy of users’ needs is a necessary skill for being a good UX designer and for being a good salesperson.

There are some factors that may inhibit a salesperson becoming a good UX designer in the general sense, but they depend more on the kind of salesperson the person was; a very competent used car salesperson may be very unethical and not have the customer’s best interests at heart, focusing instead on misdirection and deceit.

Being a good salesperson doesn’t make someone a good UX designer, but it doesn't preclude them from being one either. Being a salesperson, as with any other vocation, provides a person with a set of skills.

Developing skills as a UX designer requires more than being a competent sales person, but being well-rounded is never a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can promote yourself that,

- you have deep understanding with the end users
- Understanding their needs and know how to communicate effectively to
  end users
- Can    interpret what end users need by observing them Gather
- Gather requirements  effectively from the users.